# Error when building a c driver

Tags: c, visual-studio, mongodb, driver

I had download the source code and SCONS tools. Then I try to run "scons" to build, but the build fails with the following output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Compiling for amd64
Checking for C type int64_t... (cached) no
Checking for C type int64_t... (cached) yes
Checking for C library json... (cached) no

scons: warning: Two different environments were specified for target bson.lib,
        but they appear to have the same action: ${TEMPFILE('$AR $ARFLAGS /OUT:$TARGET $SOURCES')}
File "D:\c\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.0.4\mongodb-mongo-c-driver-8f3bf8e\SConstruct", line 170, in <modu
le>
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
link /nologo /dll /out:mongoc.dll /implib:mongoc.lib ws2_32.lib src\md5.obj src\mongo.obj src\env_wi
n32.obj src\gridfs.obj src\bson.obj src\numbers.obj src\encoding.obj
env_win32.obj : error LNK2005: mongo_clear_errors 已经在 mongo.obj 中定义
   正在创建库 mongoc.lib 和对象 mongoc.exp
mongoc.dll : fatal error LNK1169: 找到一个或多个多重定义的符号
scons: *** [mongoc.dll] Error 1169
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

The key message means: when linking, it found `mongo_clear_errors` was defined more than once, the definitions are in `mongo.c` and `env_win32.c`.

How to erase this error? i am working with visual studio 2011 in win7 64-bits.

thanks all.

Comment: Are those Chinese characters?

Comment: Have you tried with the latest version of the C driver (0.6): https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver ?  The change notes mention some fixes for SCons + Makefile that may be relevant.